# Adding event to default calendar

Tags: android

I am making an appointment scheduler app. In which I am taking name, date of appointment and time of appointment then when user clicks on ok button I want event to be added in the default google calendar. But I am not able to do it can any one please tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance:
did what u suggested Pravin this is what LOG cat is saying

```
02-21 07:40:33.525: D/AndroidRuntime(1510): Shutting down VM
02-21 07:40:33.525: W/dalvikvm(1510): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a84ba8)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): Process: com.example.scheduler, PID: 1510
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL nullevents
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1186)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.example.scheduler.Alert$2.onClick(Alert.java:85)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 07:40:33.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 07:40:42.285: I/Choreographer(1541): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-21 07:40:42.705: I/Choreographer(1541): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-21 07:40:42.905: D/gralloc_goldfish(1541): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way to do it as follows :-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is another way is

Get a reference to the calendar with this method 
(It is highly recommended not to use this method, because it could break on newer Android versions):

```
private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {

    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }
    }
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

and add an event and a reminder this way:

```
// get calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// event insert
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", "Reminder Title");
values.put("allDay", 0);
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
values.put("description", "Reminder description");
values.put("visibility", 0);
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

// reminder insert
Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
values = new ContentValues();
values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put( "method", 1 );
values.put( "minutes", 10 );
cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

You'll also need to add these permissions to your manifest for this method:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier too and I am trying this thing this time too. But every time I click on the button it says "Before you add an event you must add atleast one calendar account" then I added the account but it says the same thing again.and I m trying to run it on emulator. Do you think it will work well on android phones and not work well on emulator. Please suggest me something. THANKS

Comment: DID what you suggested now it is force closing when i click on the button this is what LOG CAT is saying:

Comment: check first if there is any calender registered with any account ot not.

Comment: thanks much pravin... Your first reply was working just the difference it was not working on emulator but worked in my android phone.